# Use PVA skillbot in Bot Framework Bot (without Composer)

Tags: botframework, power-virtual-agents

Is it possible to connect a PVA skillbot to a Bot Framework Bot (not one built with Composer)? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-use-pva-as-a-skill) shows how to connect it in Composer which involves exporting a manifest and intents file from PVA, then importing them into Composer, but it doesn't really explain what happens in the background, or how this can be achieved in a bot built programmatically. There also isn't any documentation on what a payload to the PVA endpoint should look like, nor what authentication it requires.